# Collapsing character vectors with sprintf instead of paste

Tags: string, r, printf, paste

I have mostly used `paste` or `paste0` for my pasting tasks in the past, but I'm pretty fascinated by the speed of  `sprintf`. Yet I feel that I'm lacking some its basics.

Just wondered if there's also a way to collapse a multi-element character vector to one of length 1 as `paste` would do when using its `collapse` argument, that is, **without having to specify respective wildcards and its values manually** (in `paste`, I simply leave the task up to the function to find out how many elements should be collapsed).

```
x <- c("Pasted string:", "hello", "world!")

> sprintf("%s %s %s", x[1], x[2], x[3])
[1] "Pasted string: hello world!"
> paste(x, collapse=" ")
[1] "Pasted string: hello world!"
```

I'm looking for something like this (pseudo code)

```
> sprintf("<the-correct-parameter>", x)
[1] "Pasted string: hello world"
```

---

For the interested: benchmark of `sprintf` vs. `paste`

```
require("microbenchmark")
t1 <- median(microbenchmark(sprintf("%s %s %s", x[1], x[2], x[3]))$time)
t2 <- median(microbenchmark(paste(x, collapse=" "))$time)

> t1/t2
[1] 0.7273114
```

Comment: I do not fully get what you are asking but maybe this is interesting https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-May/104898.html

Comment: I tried to make it a bit clearer. AFAIK, `sprintf` requires me to explicitly state wildcards while `paste` does not (which is the feature I like about `paste`).

Comment: `paste` and `sprintf` simply fulfil different purposes, don’t try to supplant one by the other: `sprintf` *formats*, `paste` concatenates.

Comment: Ok, I get your point that it's not a good route to pursue. But technically speaking you *can* also use `sprintf` to concatenate, can't you (`sprintf("%s some other text %s", "a", "b")`)?

Comment: @Rappster For a fixed number of elements, sure, because concatenating a fixed number of elements inside a string happens to be a specific formatting.

Answer (score 1):

The function sprintf recycles its format string, so for example the code

```
cat(sprintf("%8.4f",rnorm(5)),"\n")
```

prints something like

-0.5685  -0.6481   0.6296  -0.0043  -1.4763

```
str = sprintf("%8.4f",rnorm(5))
```

stores the output in a vector of strings and

```
str_one = paste(sprintf("%8.4f",rnorm(5)),collapse='')
```

stores the output in a single string. The format string does not need to specify the number of floats to be printed. This also holds for printing integers and strings with the %d and %s formats.

Comment: Thanks, again something learned :-) But I'm looking for a way to asign the resulting character vector of length 1 to a variable. `cat` "just" prints it. Could use `capture.output`, but that feels like chasing your own tail ;-)

Comment: Changed answer to address your question.

Comment: But this still gives me a vector of length `5`. `paste(..., collapse="")` returns a vector of length 1. That's the crucial part.